# "Программа завершила работу с ненулевым кодом возврата" почему так происходит и что это значит

Tags: python, python-3.x

На сайте где я компилирую код пишет: *"Программа завершила работу с ненулевым кодом возврата"* как это исправить и что это такое?

Вот код:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
d = a + b
print(d)
```

Comment: Зачем это исправлять?

Comment: на сайте было задание написать код который выдает сумму чисел, я написал код но ответ не верный и выдает это сообщение

Comment: Как точно звучит задание?

Comment: Вычислите сумму двух целых чисел.

Формат ввода
Первая строка входа содержит два целых числа A и B, не превосходящих по абсолютной величине 1000.

Формат вывода
Выведите одно число — сумму чисел из входного файла.

Comment: На входе одна строка с двумя числами,  а ваш код ждёт две строки по одному числу.

Comment: Не понял, можно по подробнее

Comment: На входе дают "34 45 <ввод>", а ваш код принимает "34 <ввод>", "45 <ввод>" .

Comment: Значит надо написать a = int(input()) + int(input()).  Или как?

Comment: Вы просто написали абсолютно тот же самый код, что в вопросе, но без `print` и в одну строчку. Требуется справиться с вызовом `input()` всего один раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в задача сказано что надо вводить данные в одну строку, а у вас в две

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

с помощью метода `split` разделяем значения по пробелу, а с помощью `map` превращаем все элементы вчисло

Comment: Спасибо большое.